# MPU-6050, why is pitch, yaw and roll data not being consistent (value keeps getting higher/lower when it is stable)?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I recently bought a MPU 6050 that I plan to use with a drone. However I face some difficulties now because the MPU is not giving me steady results.

The results (pitch, roll, yaw) i get are not consistent. If I for example keep the chip stable on a table the value keeps increasing/decreasing even though it is not being touched/moved.

I also seem to get different results if i restart it even though i use it at the same angles.

Is something off with my code or is there anything else I need to do in order to fix this issue?

Appreciate any help I can get! :)

Here is my current code:

```
#include <Servo.h> 
#include <Wire.h>

int gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z;
long acc_x, acc_y, acc_z, acc_total_vector;
int temperature;
long gyro_x_cal, gyro_y_cal, gyro_z_cal;
long loop_timer;
int lcd_loop_counter;
float angle_pitch, angle_roll;
int angle_pitch_buffer, angle_roll_buffer;
boolean set_gyro_angles;
float angle_roll_acc, angle_pitch_acc;
float angle_pitch_output, angle_roll_output;


void setup() {

Wire.begin();       
Serial.begin(9600);                                          

setup_mpu_6050_registers();                   
for (int cal_int = 0; cal_int < 2000 ; cal_int ++){ 

read_mpu_6050_data(); 
gyro_x_cal += gyro_x;     
gyro_y_cal += gyro_y; 
gyro_z_cal += gyro_z;
delay(3);             
}

gyro_x_cal /= 2000;
gyro_y_cal /= 2000;  
gyro_z_cal /= 2000;   
loop_timer = micros(); 

}

void loop(){

read_mpu_6050_data();                        

gyro_x -= gyro_x_cal;           
gyro_y -= gyro_y_cal;                                    
gyro_z -= gyro_z_cal;

angle_pitch += gyro_x * 0.0000611;  
angle_roll += gyro_y * 0.0000611;  

angle_pitch += angle_roll * sin(gyro_z * 0.000001066);   
angle_roll -= angle_pitch * sin(gyro_z * 0.000001066); 

acc_total_vector = sqrt((acc_x*acc_x)+(acc_y*acc_y)+(acc_z*acc_z));
angle_pitch_acc = asin((float)acc_y/acc_total_vector)* 57.296; 
angle_roll_acc = asin((float)acc_x/acc_total_vector)* -57.296;     

angle_pitch_acc -= 0.0;                      
angle_roll_acc -= 0.0;                  

if(set_gyro_angles){                     
angle_pitch = angle_pitch * 0.9996 + angle_pitch_acc * 0.0004;
angle_roll = angle_roll * 0.9996 + angle_roll_acc * 0.0004;
}
else{                                             
angle_pitch = angle_pitch_acc;                                   
angle_roll = angle_roll_acc;                                 
set_gyro_angles = true; 
}

Serial.println(angle_pitch_output);
Serial.println(angle_roll_output);

while(micros() - loop_timer < 4000); 
loop_timer = micros(); 
}


void read_mpu_6050_data(){    

Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);     
Wire.write(0x3B);                     
Wire.endTransmission(); 
Wire.requestFrom(0x68,14);           
while(Wire.available() < 14);          
acc_x = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();           
acc_y = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();             
acc_z = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();              
temperature = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                 
gyro_x = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();               
gyro_y = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();             
gyro_z = Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();                     

}



void setup_mpu_6050_registers(){

Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);         
Wire.write(0x6B);                  
Wire.write(0x00);                                                   
Wire.endTransmission();                                              

Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);           
Wire.write(0x1C);                 
Wire.write(0x10);               
Wire.endTransmission();   
Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);       
Wire.write(0x1B);                    
Wire.write(0x08);                   
Wire.endTransmission(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you put together pieces of code you found on the internet ? Can you tell where you found them ? It is a confusing mix of different programming styles and the formulas, the usage of the Wire library, the mixing of int, long and float are also confusing. The MPU-9250 has a magnetometer for the yaw. There are a number of good libraries for sensor fusion with filters for the 6DOF or 9DOF sensors. The MPU-6050 and MPU-9250 can also use the internal dmp firmware. You could start with the Sparkfun.com website and search for MPU-9250.

Comment: I do not use mpu-9250, i use the mpu-6050. And yea when it comes to the code i have found it everywhere and put together something on my own also which makes it a bit chaotic!

Comment: The MPU-6050 is outdated and the modules on Ebay could have a wrong capacitor making it even more noisier. Can you give a reference for those formulas ? Without reference I have a lot of doubts. Looking at the code, I even have doubts about the 4ms delay. Your loop is probably more slowed down by the full output buffer of Serial than by micros(). I strongly suggest to use a library and you might consider to buy a MPU-9250. Are you perhaps using a 5V Arduino without I2C level shifter ?

Comment: I bought it from ebay so perhaps the quality is not great :( My arduino has a I2C i believe.
Do you think this example could work well? https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-MPU6050/blob/master/MPU6050_gyro_pitch_roll_yaw/MPU6050_gyro_pitch_roll_yaw.ino

Comment: I see some problems: the use of the Wire library is wrong (a endTransmission after requestFrom, a while loop after requestFrom); no sensor fusion; shifting a 8-bit variable 8 times to the left. This one tests new formulas. I think the results are a little noisy. Remove the display calls: https://github.com/kriswiner/MPU-6050/blob/master/MPU6050IMU.ino  This one works: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=58048.0  This one is most often used: https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050 but there have been some complaints that it does not use a real Kalman filter.